# "File script1.py is being edited by x (with nano 7.2, PID xxxxx); open anyway?" - trouble switching between nano files

Tags: command-line, nano

I just created two python scripts in nano: script1.py and script2.py. I'm currently editing script2.py, switching back and forth between script and terminal using the `fg` command (in the terminal) and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (in nano).

I would now like to go back to editing script1.py. I tried doing this by writing

```
nano script1.py
```

in the terminal. The following message popped up:

```
File script1.py is being edited by vadim (with nano 7.2, PID xxxxx); open anyway?
```

with options 'Yes', 'No' and 'Cancel'. I'm not sure what 'Yes' would do to the file, so I chose 'Cancel'.

I went back to script2.py using `fg` and tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to move forwards and backwards between nano files as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816699/how-to-open-multiple-files-and-switch-between-them-in-nano-text-editor) post but this only resulted in the message

```
[ No more open file buffers ]
```

being displayed in nano.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287798/file-server-js-is-being-edited-by-root-with-nano-2-4-2-pid-xxxx-continue) related post hasn't helped either.

How does one go about switching between files in nano?